# Dynamic allocation with charactere array

Tags: c

I try to add a string dynamically allocate an element but there is a thing  in my function "ajouter_element" "add_element" it's in the malloc but i don't know how it does work

```
void ajouter_element(liste* liste, chaine val){
    element* listeCourante;
    element* parcourt;
    parcourt = *liste; //Cette element sert de pointeur ppour parcourir la liste pour ne pas perde la tete de la liste
    listeCourante = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element)); // on alloue de la place dans cette liste
    strcpy(listeCourante->val,val); // puis on ajoute la valeur entrée au clavier dans ce nouvelle element
    listeCourante->svt=NULL; //comme on l'ajoute a la fin l'element suivant est donc NULL
    if(parcourt==NULL){
         *liste=listeCourante; //si la liste de depart est NULL on ajoute directement l'element
    }else{
         printf("pk");
         while(parcourt->svt!=NULL){//on parcourt la liste pour pouvoir ajouter a la fin il faut que le pointeur pointe sur le derniere element
            printf("pk");
            parcourt=parcourt->svt;
        }
        parcourt->svt=listeCourante;
    }
}
```

My main to ensure that the program works

```
int main(){

  liste liste;
  chaine valeur;
  valeur=(chaine)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
  initialisation(&liste);
  afficher_liste(liste);

  printf(" Entrez un mot (TAPEZ * POUR ARRETER LA BOUCLE) :   \n");
  scanf("%s",valeur); //on lit la valeur a jouter au clavier
  while(strcmp(valeur,"*")!=0){ // * est le marqueur pour arreter la boucle
    printf("ca marche 2.0");
    ajouter_element(&liste,valeur);
    printf(" Entrez un mot (TAPEZ * POUR ARRETER LA BOUCLE) :   \n");
    scanf("%s",valeur);
    printf("ca marche");
  }

  afficher_liste(liste);

  printf(" \nEntrez le mot a supprimer :   \n");
  scanf("%s",valeur);
  supprimer_element(&liste,valeur);

  afficher_liste(liste);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your question? what is the type of `chaine` ? showing all the types would be better.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of guesswork since some info is missing:

`chaine` is very likely to be a typedef on a `char *` (see main program where `value` is allocated)

When you do this:

```
listeCourante = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element)); // on alloue de la place dans cette liste
```

you allocate an element. BUT you don't initialize the memory for the `val` char array. So the next statement:

```
strcpy(listeCourante->val,val); // puis on ajoute la valeur entrée au clavier dans ce nouvelle element
```

probably crashes because `listeCourante->val` has undefined value.

you have to do:

```
listeCourante->val = strdup(val);
```

instead. So memory is allocated just right and the input string is copied.

Note: you could have make your program work by defining `typedef char chaine[20];` instead of `typedef char * chaine;`

(and drop the malloc of `val` in the `main` function, use `scanf("%19s",val)` to avoid overflowing the buffer ...)